# Unpadded RSA ciphertext multiplication by 2**e breaks deciphering on a small message _sporadically_

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, modular-arithmetic

Please, help me to understand, why the snippet below fails to decrypt the message *sometimes* (it successes best 5 out 6 times) when ran multiple times.

It generates an 1024-bit `rsa` keys pair, then encrypts "Hello World!!" in most naive way possible, [doubles ciphertext](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/hom_rsa), decrypts doubled ciphertext, and finally divides the result to get original plaintext. At the step of decryption it could be clearly seen (logging `doubled_decr`) when it is going wildly off.

As the given plaintext is small, it should recover from doubling well. `bigint-mod-arith` package, used for modular exponentiation here, is maintained and have some tests (though really big numbers only in performance section) in it, was used for a number of times, and doesn't seem to be a cause.

```js
import {generateKeyPairSync, privateDecrypt, publicEncrypt, constants} from "node:crypto";
import * as modAr from "bigint-mod-arith";

//  "Generate a 1024 bit RSA key pair." https://cryptopals.com/sets/6/challenges/46
const keys = generateKeyPairSync("rsa", {modulusLength: 1024});

let jwk_export = keys.privateKey.export({format: "jwk"});
let pt_test = Buffer.from("Hello World!!");
let ct_test  = naiveEncrypt(pt_test, keys.publicKey);
let doubled = bigintFromBuf(ct_test) 
    * modAr.modPow(2, bigintFromParam(jwk_export.e), bigintFromParam(jwk_export.n));
let doubled_decr = naiveDecrypt(Buffer.from(doubled.toString(16), "hex"), keys.privateKey);
console.debug(pt_test, "plaintext buffer");
console.debug(doubled_decr, "homomorphically doubled buffer (after decryption)");
console.debug(
    "_Decrypted doubled buffer divided back by 2 and converted to text_:", 
    Buffer.from((bigintFromBuf(doubled_decr) / 2n).toString(16), "hex").toString()
)

function bigintFromParam(str) {return bigintFromBuf(Buffer.from(str, "base64url"))}
function bigintFromBuf(buf) {return BigInt("0x" + buf.toString("hex"))}

function naiveEncrypt(message, publicKey) {
    const keyParameters = publicKey.export({format: "jwk"});
    // console.debug(bigintFromParam(keyParameters.e));
    // console.debug(bigintFromParam(keyParameters.n));
    return Buffer.from(modAr.modPow(
        bigintFromBuf(message),
        bigintFromParam(keyParameters.e),
        bigintFromParam(keyParameters.n)    
    ).toString(16), "hex");
}

function naiveDecrypt(message, privateKey) {
    const keyParameters = privateKey.export({format: "jwk"});
    // console.debug(bigintFromParam(keyParameters.d));
    console.assert(
        bigintFromParam(keyParameters.e) == modAr.modInv(
            bigintFromParam(keyParameters.d), 
            (bigintFromParam(keyParameters.q) - 1n) * (bigintFromParam(keyParameters.p) - 1n) 
        )
    );
    return Buffer.from(modAr.modPow(
        bigintFromBuf(message),
        bigintFromParam(keyParameters.d),
        bigintFromParam(keyParameters.n)    
    ).toString(16), "hex");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems, one fundamental and one 'just coding':

- you need to divide the 'doubled' plaintext by 2 *in the modular ring Zn not the plain integers Z*. In general to divide in Zn we modular-multiply by the modular inverse -- a over b = a*modInv(b,n)%n -- but for the particular case of 2 we can simplify to just a/2 or (a+n)/2
- when you take `bigint.toString(16)` the result is variable length depending on the value of the bigint. Since RSA cryptograms are for practical purposes uniform random numbers in [2,n-1], with a 1024-bit key most of the time the result is 128 digits, but about 1/16 of the time is it 127 digits, 1/256 of the time it is 126 digits, etc. If the number of digits is odd, doing `Buffer.from(hex,'hex')` throws away the last digit and produces a value that is very wrong for your purpose.

  In *standard* RSA we conventionally represent all cryptograms and signatures as a byte string of fixed length equal to the length needed to represent n -- for a 1024-bit key *always* 128 bytes even if that includes leading zeros. For your hacky scheme, it is sufficient if we have an even number of digits -- 126 is okay, but not 127.

I simplified your code some to make it easier for me to test -- in particular I compute the bigint versions of n,e,d once and reuse them -- but only really changed `bigintToBuf` and `halve=` per above, to get the following which works for me (in node>=16 so 'crypto' supports jwk export):

```
const modAr=require('bigint-mod-arith'); // actually I use the IIFE for reasons but that makes no difference
const jwk=require('crypto').generateKeyPairSync('rsa',{modulusLength:1024}).privateKey.export({format:'jwk'});
const n=bigintFromParam(jwk.n), e=bigintFromParam(jwk.e), d=bigintFromParam(jwk.d);
function bigintFromParam(str){ return bigintFromBuf(Buffer.from(str,'base64url')); }
function bigintFromBuf(buf){ return BigInt('0x'+buf.toString('hex')); }
function bigintToBuf(x){ let t=x.toString(16); return Buffer.from(t.length%2?'0'+t:t,'hex');}

let plain=Buffer.from('Hello world!');
let encr=bigintToBuf(modAr.modPow(bigintFromBuf(plain),e,n));
let double=bigintToBuf(bigintFromBuf(encr)*modAr.modPow(2n,e,n))
// should actually take mod n there to get an in-range ciphertext,
// but the modPow(,,n) in the next step = decrypt fixes that for us
let decr=bigintToBuf(modAr.modPow(bigintFromBuf(double),d,n));
let temp=bigintFromBuf(decr), halve=bigintToBuf(temp%2n? (temp+n)/2n: temp/2n);
console.log(halve.toString());
```

PS: real RSA implementations, including the 'crypto' module, don't use modPow(,d,n) for decryption, they use the "Chinese Remainder" parameters in the private key to do a more efficient computation instead. See wikipedia for a good explanation.

PPS: just for the record, 1024-bit RSA -- even with decent padding -- has been considered marginal for security since 2013 at latest and mostly prohibited, although there is not yet a reported break in the open community. However, that is offtopic for SO, and your exercise clearly isn't about security.

Comment: > Buffer.from(hex,'hex') throws away the last digit
\
\ Wow, I really supposed it do the opposite. Should have checked this. Thank you! Without you it would take forever to find. \
\
Especially thank you for answering so swiftly! \
\
> ... conventionally represent all cryptograms and signatures as...
\
\ This is ultimately reasonable. What are right tools for it? Or do you each time add your own function? It surprised me to not find something relevant at `node:crypto`. So hex strings turned out to become kind of interface between bytes and bigints for me.

Comment: > real RSA implementations, including the 'crypto' module, don't use modPow(,d,n) for decryption, they use the "Chinese Remainder"...
\
\ As an addition to Wikipedia I would recommend <https://www.di-mgt.com.au/crt_rsa.html>, which is still on my reading list. They done great work explaining the topics. \
\
> but for the particular case of 2 we can simplify to
\
\ Yeah, it doesn't wrap at all, so even `(temp + n) / 2n` isn't reached _in this case_. \
\
Do you think this question should be renamed to be useful for future searchers?

Comment: (sorry for delay, I had to work on something else) I use the standard algorithms, not broken ones, and the standard algorithms in 'crypto' are complete so I don't need any added tools. If I did, adding or removing padding is a very simple loop that fits on one line. Multiply-by-2 _does_ wrap for all p>n/2 giving an odd p' which _does_ need (n+p')/2 to return the correct p. I doubt many people will be searching for this rather specific Q, but if any do I can't think of a significantly better title.